# call functions on a specific level of a numpy ndarray without for loops

Tags: numpy

suppose a numpy ndarrary

```
arr
```

has shape (100,100,5,5)

The following codes work:

```
result=np.zeros((arr.shape[0], arr.shape[1], 10))    
for i in range(arr.shape[0]):
        for j in range(arr.shape[1]):
           v=arr[i,j].flatten()
           hist, bi= np.histogram(v, bins=10, range=(0,3))
           result[i,j] =hist
```

but it's slow. Is there a more efficient way to write the codes, say avoid the for loops?

Comment: Why  aren't you accumulating the `hist`?

Comment: dear hpaulj, I revised the codes to save all  hist

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I thought `apply_along_axis` would help, but it doesn't seem to make much of a difference, at least at the problem sizes of interest to you. Maybe there's overhead in `myhist`.

See the code below.

```
import numpy as np
import time

low    = 0.0
high   = 3.0 
bins   = 10
arrshp = (100,100,5,5)

def myhist(xx):
    out = np.histogram(xx,bins=bins,range=(low,high))
    return out[0]


arr       = np.random.uniform(low,high,arrshp)

time1 = time.time()
arr2      = arr.reshape(arrshp[0],arrshp[1],-1)
out_fast  = np.apply_along_axis(myhist,-1,arr2) 
time2 = time.time()

print('time (secs) fast = ',time2-time1)


time3 = time.time()
out_slow  = np.zeros((arr.shape[0],arr.shape[1],bins),dtype='float64')
for i in range(arr.shape[0]):
    for j in range(arr.shape[1]):
       v   = arr[i,j].flatten()
       _hh = np.histogram(v, bins=bins, range=(low,high))
       out_slow[i,j,:] = _hh[0]
time4 = time.time()
       
print('norm diff = ',np.linalg.norm(out_fast-out_slow))
print('time (secs) slow = ',time4-time3)
```

Comment: `histogram` still has to be called 100*100 times. `apply...`isn't a compiler., and not a performance tool.

Comment: thank Nachiket! I learned a few skills from your codes. My actual problem is much larger, I will compare the running times in different approaches.

Comment: @hpaulj thanks. I was under the impression that ```apply...``` would eliminate (or convert to C) the two for loops (assuming they were the bottleneck)

Comment: @Nachiket, I tested on larger data, the performances of the two approaches are identical.